# Why should I ask a question on beta sites when I don't get enough views?

Tags: discussion, views, beta-sites

I have asked a question in [Project Management SE (Beta)](https://pm.stackexchange.com/). But, there are very low number of views generated as compared to Stack Overflow. 
This discourages me from using the topic specific beta site and ask the question in Stack Overflow itself. But, the moderators may close it for being off topic.

So, what's the solution here? Are beta sites really useful?

Shouldn't SE do something to encourage the usage of the beta sites - at least till they graduate? For example, show the questions from the beta sites that the user has signed up for, in her SO account

Comment: But do you realize that *every* site is beta at some point of time :)

Comment: Yes! Beta sites are very useful!

Comment: Define "enough views". If you have a very low number of view on a question, but still get an excellent answer, is that a problem? If so, can you explain why that is a problem?

Comment: I see the point here. The purpose of the beta sites is to generate more "quality views" and in my case, it did happen so.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> So, what's the solution here?

Ask your question on the site where it is on-topic. Sure, it gets less views than Stack Overflow **but** that doesn't mean it should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Keeping your questions to where they belong means that the **right** eyes read them.

Sure, it will (on average) take longer to get an answer on a smaller site - but is that a bad thing? If you are looking to get an answer in *minutes*, you are doing it wrong (even on Stack Overflow you shouldn't expect that).

> Are beta sites really useful?

Yes. You are much more likely to get your project management question answered and answered fully on the project management site (in the same way that your chess questions will get better answers on the chess site).

And beta sites are not in beta forever - when they show sustainable growth and self moderation they "graduate". This is true for pretty much all non-beta sites on the network.

Of course, if you **don't** ask questions on beta sites, they won't grow as fast and the likelihood of getting answers and for their graduation falls.

Comment: Or if you want more views, turn your chess questions into puzzles and ask it on PuzzlingSE. :-)

Comment: Shouldn't SE do something to encourage the usage of the beta sites - atleast till they graduate? For eg,  show the questions from the beta sites that the user has signed up for, in her SO account.

Comment: @Hariprasad - that's an interesting idea. Why not post a discussion about what can be done to promote beta sites?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252762/what-can-be-done-to-promote-beta-sites

Answer (score 3):

> So, what's the solution here?

Well, beta sites need traffic and all questions and answers there are really the foundation for future posts, so new users can see what posts are allowed and which ones are not. Views aren't really important ***yet***. As your beta site grows, so will its popularity and thus its views. By not asking, you just tried not to help separate the goodies from the baddies. So ask on the appropriate site, no matter what state it is in. So be a person and ask please.

> Are beta sites really useful?

Definitely yes beyond imagination. SE needs to grow and users want more sites with more variety. Traffic will get higher, more people will make an account, and more people will trust that site to answer his/her 's specific questions.

Need less beta? Ask and answer and moderate by voting and giving advice! Beta will graduate or at least get to the next level and not get closed with the community's support! So help them out and those beta reach graduation. These new sites will help a lot of non-users and users a lot more than you think.

> But, there are very less number of views

Well, you can simply get the Tumbleweed badge while you are waiting. It shows your patience and shows your dedication to the site, emotionally appealing to some as they want you to "not feel lonely" and want the site to graduate.