# Why is it so difficult to find the twitter account for a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, twitter, site-promotion

I am not able to find a link to the twitter account of Academia SE (https://twitter.com/StackAcademia), for example, in the Academia SE main webpage.

Why are twitter links not included on the main site page of each Q&A site in SE?

Comment: There's a twitter account?  Huh.

Comment: @jakebeal Yes, there is one. I do not know whether it is official or not, actually.

Comment: It is official. See this [blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @ff524 Ooooh, that is very interesting... But, then, again, why not to add the twitter acount in the main website?

Comment: Network-wide, the twitter link for any StackExchange site can be found in the [list of SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). (Look for the "twitter" link under the number of questions.)

Comment: Migrating to main meta on user request.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update:** Twitter bots for all Q&A sites have been shut down. [See here for more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386451/are-the-various-site-tweetbots-affected-by-the-upcoming-twitter-api-changes/386476#386476).

---

Not all sites have Twitter accounts. We stopped creating them for all public beta sites by default because a) Twitter sees very little engagement for us; b) Twitter-the-company started blocking new accounts for us (probably because it thinks we're bots?) and fighting that got too annoying and time-consuming.

Having said that, both Twitter accounts and blog links are available on https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list.

Comment: Stopped... or maybe not. [ru.SO account](https://twitter.com/ruStackOverflow) has just appeared (not yet linked on the list of sites), and [ja.SO](https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow) became fully operational 10 days ago.

Comment: @NormalHuman Yep, I made both of those. We create them when there's a definite need (such as for community managers of international Stack Overflow sites to use these accounts for more than just auto-tweeting). We stopped creating these *by default* for every site that makes it into public beta. I updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: `probably because it thinks we're bots` well... aren't most of them bots?

Comment: @enderland In the "we're posting automatically" sense, yes. Although not in the way Twitter defines that - our accounts serve an announcement purpose, not spamming. We aren't actually breaking their TOS (which is why every single one of those accounts was reinstated after a round of support requests).

Comment: @AdamLear From your answer, I understand that Twitter is not a main engagement tool for SE sites. However, twitter accounts for many SE sites exist! and I do not get the point of them not appearing mentioned somewhere in their respective main webpage. I maintain my question as unanswered.

Comment: @Vicent: I think that your question can be generalized also for those sites which have a blog: why blog links, too, do not appear in the respective main pages?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Blog links are in the site switcher.

Comment: I finally accepted this answer...

Comment: Did Twitter block one or more existing SE accounts too? Reason I ask is because of [this](https://twitter.com/StackMovies/status/1179637330375782400) tweet (the link is from the 'tweeted' event in the timeline of [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/104366/timeline) question). So it seems *Movies and TV* did once have a Twitter account, but doesn't have one now.

Comment: @stevec Most likely. We originally stopped creating new ones because the rate of them getting blocked was pretty high and then someone (usually me) would have to spend time with Twitter support trying to get unblocked. It may be time to turn off the remaining integrations, if there are still any unblocked ones left.

Comment: Note: Due to changes in Twitter's API, these Twitter bots (for the SE sites that had them) have now been shut off. [See this post for more details.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386476/335251)

Answer (score 6):

Based on [Adam's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/152859), I extracted all twitter accounts from the [sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list).

Currently there are 110 twitter accounts for SE sites:

Languages:

- [German Language](https://twitter.com/StackGerman)
- [Japanese Language](https://twitter.com/StackJapanese)
- [French Language](https://twitter.com/StackFrench)
- [Spanish Language](https://twitter.com/StackSpanish)
- [Chinese Language](https://twitter.com/StackChinese)
- [Russian Language](https://twitter.com/StackRussian)
- [English Language Learners](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL)
- [Italian Language](https://twitter.com/StackItalian)
- [English Language & Usage](https://twitter.com/StackEnglish)

Money/Finance/Economics:

- [Quantitative Finance](https://twitter.com/StackQuant)
- [Bitcoin](https://twitter.com/StackBitcoin)
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://twitter.com/StackFinance)

Maths/Statistics:

- [TeX - LaTeX](https://twitter.com/StackTeX)
- [Cross Validated](https://twitter.com/StackStats)
- [Mathematics](https://twitter.com/StackMath)
- [Mathematica](https://twitter.com/StackMma)

Stack Overflow:

- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow)

Religion:

- [Islam](https://twitter.com/StackIslam)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://twitter.com/StackJudaism)
- [Christianity](https://twitter.com/StackChristian)
- [Linguistics](https://twitter.com/StackLinguist)
- [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://twitter.com/StackBibleHerm)

Hobby/Enthusiast:

- [Movies & TV](https://twitter.com/StackMovies)
- [Poker](https://twitter.com/StackPoker)
- [Board & Card Games](https://twitter.com/StackBoardGames)
- [Role-playing Games](https://twitter.com/StackRPG)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://twitter.com/StackSciFi)
- [Pets](https://twitter.com/StackPets)
- [Beer, Wine & Spirits](https://twitter.com/BeerStack)
- [Physical Fitness](https://twitter.com/StackFitness)
- [Arqade](https://twitter.com/TheArqade)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://twitter.com/StackCooking)
- [Photography](https://twitter.com/StackPhotos)
- [The Great Outdoors](https://twitter.com/StackOutdoors)
- [Martial Arts](https://twitter.com/StackMartialArt)
- [Sports](https://twitter.com/StackSport)
- [Amateur Radio](https://twitter.com/StackHam)
- [Aviation](https://twitter.com/StackAviation)
- [Chess](https://twitter.com/StackChess)
- [Bicycles](https://twitter.com/StackBicycles)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://twitter.com/StackAndroid)
- [Ask Different](https://twitter.com/askdifferent)
- [Home Improvement](https://twitter.com/StackDIY)
- [WordPress Development](https://twitter.com/StackWordPress)
- [Ebooks](https://twitter.com/StackEbooks)
- [Space Exploration](https://twitter.com/StackSpaceExp)
- [Software Recommendations](https://twitter.com/StackSoftRecs)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://twitter.com/StackGIS)
- [Windows Phone](https://twitter.com/StackWinPhone)
- [Music: Practice & Theory](https://twitter.com/StackMusic)
- [Travel](https://twitter.com/StackTravel)

Computers:

- [Super User](https://twitter.com/super_user)
- [Web Applications](https://twitter.com/StackWebApps)
- [Webmasters](https://twitter.com/StackWebmasters)
- [Game Development](https://twitter.com/StackGameDev)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://twitter.com/AskUbuntu)
- [User Experience](https://twitter.com/StackUX)
- [Unix & Linux](https://twitter.com/StackUnix)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://twitter.com/StackCSTheory)
- [Cryptography](https://twitter.com/StackCrypto)
- [Information Security](https://twitter.com/StackSecurity)
- [Database Administrators](https://twitter.com/StackDBAs)
- [Code Review](https://twitter.com/StackCodeReview)
- [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://twitter.com/StackCodeGolf)
- [Signal Processing](https://twitter.com/StackSignals)
- [Computational Science](https://twitter.com/StackSciComp)
- [Computer Science](https://twitter.com/StackCompSci)

Natural science, computer science, engineering:

- [Chemistry](https://twitter.com/StackChemistry)
- [Biology](https://twitter.com/StackBiology)
- [Physics](https://twitter.com/StackPhysics)
- [Astronomy](https://twitter.com/StackAstronomy)
- [Software Engineering](https://twitter.com/StackSoftEng)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://twitter.com/StackElectronix)
- [Reverse Engineering](https://twitter.com/StackReverseEng)
- [Network Engineering](https://twitter.com/StackNetworkEng)
- [Robotics](https://twitter.com/StackRobotics)

Social Science, Humanities:

- [Anime & Manga](https://twitter.com/StackAnime)
- [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://twitter.com/StackPsychology)
- [History](https://twitter.com/StackHistory)
- [Writing](https://twitter.com/StackWriting)
- [Video Production](https://twitter.com/StackAVP)
- [Graphic Design](https://twitter.com/StackDesign)
- [Philosophy](https://twitter.com/StackPhilosophy)
- [Politics](https://twitter.com/StackPolitics)

Others:

- [Homebrewing](https://twitter.com/StackHomebrew)
- [Project Management](https://twitter.com/StackProjects)
- [Skeptics](https://twitter.com/StackSkeptic)
- [Drupal Answers](https://twitter.com/StackDrupal)
- [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://twitter.com/StackMechanics)
- [Parenting](https://twitter.com/StackParenting)
- [SharePoint](https://twitter.com/StackSharePoint)
- [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://twitter.com/StackSQA)
- [Gardening & Landscaping](https://twitter.com/StackGardening)
- [Bricks](https://twitter.com/StackBrix)
- [Academia](https://twitter.com/StackAcademia)
- [The Workplace](https://twitter.com/StackWorkplace)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://twitter.com/StackRaspi)
- [Salesforce](https://twitter.com/StackSalesforce)
- [Genealogy & Family History](https://twitter.com/StackGenealogy)
- [ExpressionEngine® Answers](https://twitter.com/StackExpression)
- [Magento](https://twitter.com/StackMagento)
- [Sustainable Living](https://twitter.com/StackSustain)
- [Tridion](https://twitter.com/StackTridion)
- [Open Data](https://twitter.com/StackOpenData)
- [Freelancing](https://twitter.com/StackFreelance)
- [Blender](https://twitter.com/StackBlender)
- [Tor](https://twitter.com/StackTor)
- [Arduino](https://twitter.com/StackArduino)

For those interested, I've used the following code to extract the links:

```js
var twitters = [];
$(".lv-site-resources").each(function() {
    var curItem = $(this);
    if ($.trim(curItem.text()) == "twitter") {
        var site = $.trim(curItem.parents(".lv-item").first().find(".lv-info").find("h2").text());
        var link = curItem.find("a").first().attr("href");
        if (site.length > 0) {
            twitters.push({Site: site, Link: link});
        }

    }
});
if (twitters.length > 0) {
    console.log("Found " + twitters.length + " twitter accounts:");
    console.log(twitters.map(function(t) {
        return "- [" + t.Site + "](" + t.Link + ")";
    }).join("\n"));
} else {
    console.log("No twitter accounts found");
}
```